# Pandas appending dictionary values with iterrows row values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dict of city names, each having an empty list as a value. I am trying to use
`df.iterrows()`
to append corresponding names to each dict key(city):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    dict[row['city']].append(row['fullname'])
```

Can somebody explain why the code above appends all possible 'fullname' values to each dict's key instead of appending them to their respective city keys?

I.e. instead of getting the result

```
{"City1":["Name1","Name2"],"City2":["Name3","Name4"]}
```

I'm getting

```
{"City1":["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4"],"City2":["Name1","Name2","Name3","Name4"]}
```

Edit: providing a sample of the dataframe:

```
d = {'fullname': ['Jason', 'Katty', 'Molly', 'Nicky'], 
'city': ['Arizona', 'Arizona', 'California', 'California']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Edit 2:
I'm pretty sure that my problem lies in my dict, since I created it in the following way:

```
cities = []
for i in df['city']:
    cities.append(i)
    
dict = dict.fromkeys(set(cities), [])
```

when I call dict, i get the correct output:

```
{"Arizona":[],"California":[]}
```

However if I specify a key `dict['Arizona']`, i get this:

```
{"index":[],"columns":[],"data":[]}
```

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed `.fromkeys` - the default value is evaluated once - so all of the keys are "pointing to" the same list.

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(['one', 'two'], [])
{'one': [], 'two': []}
>>> d = dict.fromkeys(['one', 'two'], [])
>>> d['one'].append('three')
>>> d
{'one': ['three'], 'two': ['three']}
```

You'd need a comprehension to create a distinct list for each key.

```
>>> d = { k: [] for k in ['one', 'two'] }
>>> d
{'one': [], 'two': []}
>>> d['one'].append('three')
>>> d
{'one': ['three'], 'two': []}
```

You are also manually implementing a groupby with your code:

```
>>> df.groupby('city')['fullname'].agg(list)
city
Arizona       [Jason, Katty]
California    [Molly, Nicky]
Name: fullname, dtype: object
```

If you want a dict:

```
>>> df.groupby('city')['fullname'].agg(list).to_dict()
{'Arizona': ['Jason', 'Katty'], 'California': ['Molly', 'Nicky']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So when would it make sense to actually use .fromkeys? If I wanted to quickly assign multiple keys and manually reassign each of their values?

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised it works at all, because `row` is a Series.

How about this alternative approach:

```
for city in your_dict.keys():
    your_dict[city] += list(df["fullname"][df["city"] == city])
```

You should always avoid iterating through dataframes unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: For some reason, it still returns the same wrong output. It appends all possible 'fullname' values to each dict's key.

Comment: Very strange! I'm reproducing your example and it's giving me the right output. Good luck!